# Interpret TLSH has values

Tags: file, hash, similarity

When I have two TLSH fuzzy hashes, e.g. :

TLSH 1: 12345678**92**0

TLSH 2: 35526328**92**2

Suppose I have something like this (of course, this is not a valid TLSH hash, but just as an example). When the last few characters are the same, in this case 92, can I conclude that the similarity is at the end of the file? I don't think so, because according to my tests, for example, when the beginning of the file is completely different, but the end is the same, then it is still possible that the beginning of the hash has different values (although the content is the same) and perhaps the end is the same (while the content is different), for example. Can anyone confirm or refute this?